# Best practice to operate on large and many buffers in OpenCl?

Tags: memory, kernel, buffer, opencl, large-data

I would like to know what options would there be to process multiple large buffers using an OpenCL kernel considering the memory limit of the device.

To put the problem into perspective imagine that these buffers represent images like the layers in
Photoshop where you combine (composite) multiple of them (in the order of tens) in order to obtain one single image. Pushing all this data into the device memory would not scale well.

I was thinking that maybe sending 2 at a time to device, doing a computation then another one and another one. But would there be a smarter solution?

Edit: lets assume that we are talking about a canvas that is 10k X 10k pixels large using 32 bit floats per channel.

Thanks!

Comment: Even integrated GPUs typically have 1GB+ of RAM at their disposal. That should be enough for any layered image.

Comment: If the canvas is 10k X 10k large and channels are 32 bit floats than you end up with over 1 Gb per layer